# Flickering Java application GUI on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java, gui

I am trying to use the [jMonkeyPlatform](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) to create a game, but the GUI of the application keeps flickering black on refreshes and resizes of the panels. I found issues on more programs that have this issue, but is there also an answer for this problem? Because I only found more problems and less solutions.

It is very frustrating to work with a flickering GUI. Does anyone has an answer to stop the flickering? I also tried to set my windows theme to Windows Basic, but that didn't work out either.

I already tried updating my java JRE, but the Java website says I have the latest already.
Installed programs:

- Java (TM) 6 Update 24
- Java (TM) 6 Update 24 (64-bit)
- Java (TM) SE Development Kit 6 Update 24 (64-bit)

The jMonkeyPlatform is a 32-bit application. My computer is on Windows 7 x64.

**Update**
I installed the Java (TM) SE Development Kit 6 Update 24 (32-bit) as well, but it didn't help. (I thought it did at first). I also found another application I'm using that is flickering as well [(BrettspielWelt)](http://www.brettspielwelt.de/Spiele/?nation=en). Is there a possible answer for this?

[image: BrettspielWelt flickering]

**Update**
I tried installing in different settings, but every setup fails in making black GUI's. I installed the following constructions:

- 32-bit JDK and JRE
- 64-bit JDK and JRE
- 32-bit JDK and JRE and 64-bit JRE
- 64-bit JDK and JRE and 32-bit JRE
- 64-bit JDK and JRE and 32-bit JDK and JRE

So, that's actually every possibility and I even found out that my Control Panel/Java is flickering, because that is also built using Java.

**Update**
I installed a new video card driver. But that doesn't solve it. This was something that I **did** change lately. I also tried the following combinations of installation without the JDK:

- 32-bit JRE only
- 32-bit JRE and 64-bit JRE
- 64-bit JRE only

But that doesn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, I managed to fix it by reinstalling my ATI Radeon HD 4900, but this time without some SDK and without the catalyst control center.

Still testing...

Answer (score 1):

Try some of the [Java 2D flags](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html), in particular `ddoffscreen` and if that doesn't work, `noddraw`:

```
java -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -jar whatever.jar
```